# Styles are not being applied with v-bind class in Vue 3

Tags: css, vue.js

```html
<template>
  <a class="nav-link" :class="activeClasses" :href="page.link.url">
    {{ page.link.text }}
  </a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["page", "isActive"],
  computed: {
    activeClasses() {
      return {
        active: this.isActive,
        emphasize: this.isActive,
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.emphasize {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}
</style>
```

I am trying to apply an underline to the navbar text but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component works as expected. Seems you're passing wrong props to your component. Here it works just fine:

```
<script setup>
  import Comp from './Comp.vue';
  import {ref} from 'vue';
  const active = ref(false);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <comp :is-active="active" :page="{link:{text:'example'}}"></comp>
  </div>
  <button @click="active = !active">Toggle</button>
</template>
```

[Vue.js Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks, Actually I want to add underline to the text of <a> which is currently selected

Comment: @owpbush I just wanted to show that's the problem in the parent component. If you find my answer useful you could upvote (the arrow up) and accept (the checkbox) it so I get reputation points and motivation to help you in the future, thanks

Comment: ok but i don't have enough reputation for arrow up.

Comment: @owpbush np, thank you, added you in my whitelist

Comment: RE my edit and the "rollback": (1) The block needs the HTML tag to be syntax highlighted correctly, as the question does not have the [tag:html] tag. (2) Components should use uppercase names. Slightly more opinionated: (3) The script blocks in Vue SFCs are normally formatted with code not indented. (4) "Normal" JavaScript formatting is to have whitespace inside object delimiters. (5) I used "Vue" instead of "Vue.js" because that's the more common name in the community. I guess which to use is almost purely opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alexander. You might want to modify your props like this:

```js
props: {
  page: { type: String, default: '' },
  isActive: { type: Boolean, default: false }
},
```